# How to perform a WHERE NOT in Laravel with query build

Tags: php, sql, orm, laravel, query-builder

Laravel query build has many where options, but I could not found a way to describe fields type `timestamp` that are not null but have an invalid value. e.g: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

`whereNull()` are not working since it is **`not null`**

`whereNot()` is treated as a invalid field `not`

I want to use the native MySQL query `NOT field` since it match with "empty" values like `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: do you want to check for those records which are 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ?

Answer (score 0):

Then, you will have to query it with `IS NULL` option. Check the ex :

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `columnname` IS NULL LIMIT 0 , 30
```

See if the following helps

```
$table->date('colname')->nullable(); 

$table->date('colname')->notnullable();
```

Comment: Good but I want it using the query builder native of the Laravel Framework. And `IS NULL` don't match with `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: How about this notNullable() OR nullable(). Which ever feasible for you !!

Comment: as in $table->date('colname')->nullable();

Comment: 'is null' checks for this "0000-00-00 00:00:00" and returns the same

Comment: Then, try this itself which is not ideal though SELECT * FROM `tn` WHERE `colname` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR SELECT * FROM `tn` WHERE `colname` <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'